# Setting background image height as a percentage

Tags: html, css

I want my background image to take up 100% of the width and only 60% of the height, I can only get the background image to display if I set the width and height using the "`vw` & "`vh`".
I tired to set as block etc.. I even gave it some content to force display the area of the image were content was present but it wont show up :(

Any ideas

```
  background-image: url("http://demo.zedtheme.com/prototype/boxed/images/example/parallax/home.jpg");
  background-position: 50% -60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7S7L2/

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```